# Kernel Module: _ASM_EXTABLE only works in virtual machine but does seem not catch page fault otherwise

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Consider the following minimal example of kernel module that attempts to write to a non-mapped page, and tries to continue execution but handling the exception through the exception table:

```c
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("test");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("test");
MODULE_VERSION("1.01");

void inc_non_present_page(void)
{
    asm volatile("mov $0, %%rax;"
                 "1: inc (%%rax);"
                 "2:nop\t\n"
                 "\t.section .fixup,\"ax\"\n"
                 "3:\tnop\n"
                 "\tjmp\t2b\n"
                 "\t.previous\n" _ASM_EXTABLE(1b, 3b)
                 :
                 :
                 : "%rax");
    pr_warn("Init done\n");
}

static int __init lkm_example_init(void)
{
    inc_non_present_page(); 
    return 0;
}
module_init(lkm_example_init);

static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, World!\n");
}
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);
```

Compiled with the makefile:

```make
obj-m += reproducer.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Running this on my virtual machine (running `Debian Bookworm`, Linux kernel v6.0.12 `6.0.0-6-amd64`) works fine -- but running this on the host (Fedora Linux 36, Linux kernel v6.0.11 `6.0.11-200.fc36.x86_64`) the module crashes with the error message:

```auto
[36053.061936] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
[36053.061938] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
[36053.061940] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[36053.061943] Oops: 0002 [#3] PREEMPT SMP PTI
[36053.061946] CPU: 1 PID: 116017 Comm: insmod Tainted: G      D    OE      6.0.11-200.fc36.x86_64 #1
[36053.061951] RIP: 0010:inc_non_present_page+0xc/0x1a [reproducer2]
[36053.061957] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0xffffffffc0ae6fe2.
```

It is totally unclear to me why that is the case? How can I go about debugging this? I tried catching another exception (divide by zero) like so:

```c
void blatant_div_by_zero(void)
{
        /* quotient and divisor */
        int q, d;

        d = 0;
        asm volatile ("movl $20, %%eax;"
        "movl $0, %%edx;"
        "1: div %1;"
        "movl %%eax, %0;"
        "2:\t\n"
        "\t.section .fixup,\"ax\"\n"
        "3:\tmov\t$-1, %0\n"
        "\tjmp\t2b\n"
        "\t.previous\n"
        _ASM_EXTABLE(1b, 3b)
        : "=r"(q)
        : "b"(d)
        :"%eax"
        );

        pr_warn("quotient is %d\n", q);
}
```

-- this seems to work fine on the host as well.

Comment: I have the same problem, not able to catch a page fault and the system crashes. But am able to catch Divide by zero exception as you said. Did anything work for you ?

Comment: I gave up eventually, and reloaded the same kernel module under a different name for quick trial & error tests. So I am still looking for a solution..